# Leader Board for Michael Jackson The Experience for Kinect

Tags: kinect, michael-jackson-the-experience

Where is the leader board(s) for Michael Jackson The Experience for Kinect?

The game's site: http://theexperience-thegame.ubi.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper URL for the game's site is http://theexperience-thegame.ubi.com/michael-jackson/en-US/home/index.aspx

According to this review...

http://www.gamingtruth.com/2011/04/14/michael-jackson-the-experience-kinect-review/

...the Xbox 360 version of the game doesn't have an online leaderboard.  I think the PS3 version of the game does have it, though.